# set alerts in tradingview without having to rely on server side (only allowed 1 alert on free account)

Tags: pine-script, alerts

I have a free account on tradingview and they have a limit on the number of alerts you can set because apparently all alerts work off their server. it apparently gets set on the server and once the condition is met, it's the server that triggers the alert.

But I can't stop thinking there has to be some kind of way to coax the pinescript and tradingview (or chrome) to trigger alerts locally.

The following code will implement a wavetrend indicator

```
study(title="Wave Trend") // name of the indicator

n1 = input(10, "Channel Length") 
n2 = input(21, "Average Length") 
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1") 
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2") 
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1") 
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2") 

ap = hlc3 
esa = ema(ap, n1) 
d = ema(abs(ap - esa), n1) 
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d) 
tci = ema(ci, n2) 

wt1 = tci 
wt2 = sma(wt1,4) 

plot(0, title="Zero Line") 
plot(obLevel1, title="Overbought Lv.1") 
plot(obLevel2, title="Overbought Lv.2") 
plot(osLevel1, title="Oversold Lv.1") 
plot(osLevel2, title="Oversold Lv.2") 

plot(wt1, title="WT Bull Line") 
plot(wt2, title="WT Bear Line") 
plot(wt1-wt2, style=area, transp=80, title="Histo") 
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 3, title="WT Crossing Outline") 
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 2, title="WT Crossing Dots") 

// Set Alerts for Bull/Bear Cross 
wtCross = cross(wt1, wt2) 
alertcondition(wtCross, title="Wave Trend Crossing", message="Wave Trend Crossing")
```

That last part is the alert that will require me to go to the alert settings on the right hand panel and manually set up the server side alert for the indicator.

What I'm looking for is a way to trigger that alert in chrome on tradingview website, using pinescript or some other means.

Any thoughts would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger alerts locally as the script is running on the servers. Would need a local Pine runtime environment and such a thing doesn't exist, afaik.

Comment: You can have one `alertcondition()` call trigger on multiple conditions, but those conditions need to be defined in the same script as the `alertcondition()` call. In cases where multiple conditions can trigger an alert, you will need to plot different markers on the chart for each condition, so you can know which condition triggered the alert. See here for an example of this technique: https://www.tradingview.com/script/8AUuFonD-5-MAs-w-alerts-LucF/
Also, you can have one alert trigger on the same condition checked on multiple symbols using `security()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic alert and change the Message according to the scenario inside the Script?
Once fired the Alert goes "yellow" but once you reset the Condition and Message, does it go "green" again automatically? Do you care if you overwrite the Condition / Message for an Alert that did not trigger? I mean, is your indicator triggering so frequently that the Price moving averages would miss, assuming the Alert turns on with the Condition / Message change?

Comment: by one alert, I mean one alert with a condition. i can't have more than one alert with different conditions. and how often it triggers is not the issue. the one alert i'm allowed triggers all day long as long the condition is met (right now I have it set to go off when the price drops 0.3% in one bar. and it triggers fine).  But I want to be keep that alert and its condition and add a new one as my current post talks about.